# Excel VBA - formula inserted by code is not calculating

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Good evening,

I'm struggling with my code. Main problem is **not calculating formula automatically**.
Formula is inserted by VBA (Left function)
I've tried multiple solutions, but nothing works:

- automatically calculated formulas are switched on
- I've tried ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General" - doesnt work
- I've tried Application.Volatile - doesnt work
- Recording text to columns and assign cells to "general" (works, but not when Im putting code into my script)

Could you please help me where lies the problem?

```
Sub QualityCheck()


'załóż filtry, wyszukaj nagłowka "vendor" i posortuj

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range("F1").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.Find(What:="Vendor", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("K1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'statystyki

    'znajdz wszystkie te same numery vendora i ostatni aktywny ROW
    i = 2
    r = 2
    koniec = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Do Until Range("K" & r) < koniec

            Do Until Range("K" & i) <> Range("K" & i + 1)

                    Range("N" & i).Select
                    Formula = "=left(M" & i & ";1)"
                    Range("N" & i).Formula = Formula  'OFFSET DODAC ALBO COS

                    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"

                i = i + 1 'i to bedzie nasz ostatni row
            Loop

        r = r + 1
    Loop

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
Range("N" & i).Select
Formula = "=left(M" & i & ";1)"
Range("N" & i).Formula = Formula
```

To

```
Range("N" & i).Formula = "=left(M" & i & ",1)"
```

I suspect that the problem is that you've used `;` instead of `,` in separating the parameters of the `left` function.

It's worth noting that you're going in a round about way of setting the formula by setting it to a variant variable and then setting it to the formula, that isn't declared by the way. Adding `Option Explicit` to the top helps catch a lot of errors like misspelled variable names and never really hurts.

On another note, it's never a bad idea to learn how to avoid select as it poses its own problems. Please see [How to avoid using Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/10361731)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Glad the solution worked for you